# Import pyalps error

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, package

I am trying to run ALPS project (Algorithms and Libraries for Physics Simulations) using Python. I have installed libraries, but when I try to import pyalps package I get error:
[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8ske.png)

What should I do?

Comment: Report it to alps devs?

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do?

You should provide more details, and as text in your question and not as an image.

1. How did you install Python?
2. How did you install SciPy?
3. How did you install alps?
4. Do you have a C compiler installed?

What we can gather from your error log is that what is failing to load is SciPy `scipy.special` module. This could be because you installed a binary package that is not compatible with your interpreter, for instance.